# Has anyone seen this Issue Tracking software feature before?

Tags: helpdesk

We're looking to get some software written if we can't find one on the market.

Has anyone ever seen Issue Tracking Software that allows the user to log their own issue on a website?  One where they have to choose the category of their problem?

The particular feature that we are after though, is that they will then receive an automated email telling them how long it will likely take to resolve their issue (based on how long previous tickets of that type took).  It will also tell them where they are in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-the-box, I don't suspect the "guesstimate" feature is something common in many ticketing systems -- I haven't seen it.

You would likely need to just design some business logic and implement using the system's built-in triggers/macros/notifications.  Since you're basing the response time on issue category [which is an almost ubiquitous ticket system notion] I don't suspect this would be very difficult.

We're using [zendesk](http://zendesk) for our web-based ticket system.  It accepts user submissions via web or email.  It is simple to customize the notification message based on the user-selected category.  Many other web-based systems will offer similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

TrackIT by Numara Software does this.
http://www.numarasoftware.com/track-it/help_desk_software.aspx

[image: screenshot]

Below this dropdown is the Description field.  Our user-defined priorities include urgent, high and low.  The Call Nack Number, which I blocked out, is auto populated from AD.  It also pulls the username from AD.

You would have to ask them about the other part of your question.  The end user does get an auto-response email, but I don't know how configurable this is. Ours is generic.